# What is the difference between enum and example in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger-2.0, openapi

In OpenAPI, both **example** and **enum** can be defined with `type: string`, such as:

```
type: string
example:
      - FOOD
      - WATER

type: string
enum:
      - FOOD
      - WATER
```

What difference does it make in terms of validation using any of the above structure? Can the above be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 0):

`enum` and `example` have different meaning and are used for different purposes.

`enum` specifies **possible values** for an instance (in other words, it *limits* possible values). It's an analog of [enums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) in C#, Java, and other programming languages. For example, `enum: [FOOD, WATER]` means that the value can be either `"FOOD"` or `"WATER"`, and nothing else.

`example` specifies an **example value** for documentation or other purposes (but not for validation). Say, if you have the `User` schema with the `username` property, you can specify *demoUser* as an example username. But the `example` value is not the *only* possible value for the property, it can have other values.

```yaml
User:
  type: object
  property:
    username:
      type: string
      example: demoUser
```

A schema can have both `enum` and `example`:

```yaml
type: string
enum:
  - FOOD
  - WATER
example: WATER
```

Unlike `enum`, `example` does not affect validation. However, tools like code generators and documentation generators may expect that the `example` values match their schemas. Such tools would flag the example in your question as invalid, because the schema is defined as `string`, but the example value is an array (i.e. a different data type).

```yaml
type: string
# Incorrect
example:
  - FOOD
  - WATER

# Correct
example: FOOD
```

Comment: The swagger schema validation is not differentiating between enum and example, i.e. if I add a value other than enum values, still the swagger validation works fine, unless explicit validation is done. Also the above example with multiple values for example with type string is working fine.

Comment: This is probably a bug in the validation library that you use.